# Kafka Producer Thread, huge amound of threads even when no message is send

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I profiled my kafka producer spring boot application and found many "kafka-producer-network-thread"s running (47 in total). Which would never stop running, even when no data is sending.

My application looks a bit like this:

```
var kafkaSender = KafkaSender(kafkaTemplate, applicationProperties)
kafkaSender.sendToKafka(json, rs.getString("KEY"))
```

with the KafkaSender:

```
@Service
class KafkaSender(val kafkaTemplate: KafkaTemplate<String, String>, val applicationProperties: ApplicationProperties) {

@Transactional(transactionManager = "kafkaTransactionManager")
fun sendToKafka(message: String, stringKey: String) {
   kafkaTemplate.executeInTransaction { kt ->
       kt.send(applicationProperties.kafka.topic, System.currentTimeMillis().mod(10).toInt(), System.currentTimeMillis().rem(10).toString(),
               message)
   }
}

companion object {
    val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaSender::class.java)!!
}
}
```

Since each time I want to send a message to Kafka I instantiate a new KafkaSender, I thought a new thread would be created which then sends the message to the kafka queue.
Currently it looks like a pool of producers is generated, but never cleaned up, even when none of them has anything to do.

Is this behaviour intended?

In my opinion the behaviour should be nearly the same as datasource pooling, keep the thread alive for some time, but when there is nothing to do, clear it up.

Comment: How does it work if you don’t use an `executeInTransaction`? You already have there a `@Transactional` based on Kafka TX manager

Comment: I am using `executeInTransaction`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using transactions, the producer cache grows on demand and is not reduced.

If you are producing messages on a listener container (consumer) thread; there is a producer for each topic/partition/consumer group. This is required to solve the zombie fencing problem, so that if a rebalance occurs and the partition moves to a different instance, the transaction id will remain the same so the broker can properly handle the situation.

If you don't care about the zombie fencing problem (and you can handle duplicate deliveries), set the `producerPerConsumerPartition` property to false on the `DefaultKafkaProducerFactory` and the number of producers will be much smaller.

**EDIT**

Starting with version 2.8 the default EOSMode is now V2 (aka BETA); which means it is no longer necessary to have a producer per topic/partition/group - as long as the broker version is 2.5 or later.

Comment: Is there documentation about the producer cache growth on transactional flows?

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for, but the cache will grow to however many concurrent transactions you may have.